# expose own service on Bluemix that in backgorund uses Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, api, hadoop, mapreduce, ibm-cloud

I want to create my own services on cloud [BlueMix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/), which can be accessed by other developers to write their applications. Basically my services (API) should use in background Apache MapReduce Java programs. One example: I want to offer a service named wordCount(String fileName) that taking one file uses Java Hadopp mapreduce API to compute the word occurences and writes the results on HDFS. Is this possible? How can I develop this in BlueMix?
Please provide detailed explanations.

Thank you
Sorin

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Develop your API application as you normally would on Bluemix using any service. Create a swagger definition and use the API Mangement service to import the swagger def and publish your API to a Bluemix org. You can manage APIs by setting rate limits, adding policies and by securing them with various user authentication requirements.